# JavaScript: querySelector - match also the top element

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible for querySelector to somehow match also the top element? So for example:

Element:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>Something</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
const container = element.querySelector('.container');
```

This won't match anything, because "container" is the top element. Is there an elegant way of querying element, that would test not only its children, but also the top element? I'm talking pure JavaScript.

Comment: I don't thing there is but you could check the contained using something like this: `element.matches('.container')`.

Answer (score 2):

You can test whether the selector refers to the top-level, and use a conditional expression:

```
const container = element.matches(".container") ? element : element.querySelector(".container");
```

For querySelectorAll you can do:

```
const containers = [...(element.matches(".container") ? [element] : []), ...element.querySelectorAll(".container")];
```

This returns an array instead of a `NodeList`, but for most purposes that difference shouldn't matter.

Comment: That would be fine, but wouldn't work with `querySelectorAll` unfortunately, I wonder if there is any more general solution, that would work for both: `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` it might be that I need to create my own tool for this, but it's a shame.

Comment: You can use `element.parent.querySelectorAll(...)`

Comment: The problem there @Barmar is that it prefers the container before the child.

Comment: What's the problem with that?

Comment: @ŁukaszZaroda Edit the question to clarify that you also want a solution that works with `querySelectorAll()`, since the best solutions are different.

Comment: The second solution will fail when the parent has multiple elements that match and `element` is not the first.

Comment: @ŁukaszZaroda You can use `[element]` instead of `element` for `querySelectorAll`, `[element]` is not a `NodeList` but it is close enough.

Answer (score 1):

Not really elegant, but this would work. 
If we resort to element.parentNode we would not guarantee targeting only the element.

```js
//dummy up
const element = document.querySelector('.container');

const container = element.querySelector('.container');

const container2 = element.querySelector('.container')||(element.classList.contains('container')) ? element : null;

console.log(container);
console.log(container2);
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>Something</div>
</div>


const container = element.querySelector('.container');
```